# Sum of revenue everyday, for last 30 days on each day

Tags: sql

I have a simple table.

```
 Date | Revenue
 5/1    12
 5/2    25
 5/3    93
 .
 .
 11/15  47
```

I am trying to write a query that returns two columns. The first column is Date, day-by-day, like the original table. The second column is 30-Day-Revenue, which is the sum of the "Revenue" column in the original table for the last 30 days, ending on the displayed date. There is a lot of overlap when we sum. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a tag for the DBMS you're using and the SQL statement you're using that's causing "a lot of overlap when we sum". Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question. I am only interested in the logic, not the exact query. I think using anything that's in standard SQL should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an alternative solution (assumes your table is called `revenue_table`):

```
SELECT a.Date, SUM(b.Revenue)
FROM revenue_table a, revenue_table b
WHERE b.Date <= a.Date AND b.Date > a.Date - 30
GROUP BY a.Date;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your logic helped me out the most. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.Date, table1.Revenue, Past30DayRevenue = SUM(table2.Revenue)
FROM    insert_your_table_name_here table1
        JOIN insert_your_table_name_here table2 ON DATEDIFF(day, table2.Date, table1.Date) BETWEEN 0 AND 29
GROUP BY table1.Date, table1.Revenue
ORDER BY table1.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [subqueries](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm). E.g.

```
SELECT outer.date, (SELECT SUM(inner.revenue) 
                    FROM table inner 
                    WHERE inner.date > outer.date-30) AS thirtydayrevenue
FROM table outer
```